# sleep_until a timepoint in the past

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-chrono

I have what I thought was a simple pattern - I want to make a timepoint 5 seconds in the future, run a task which might take a while, and then sleep until that timepoint (potentially not sleeping at all if that time has already been reached.) However, whenever trying to use `std::this_thread::sleep_until` with a timepoint in the past, my application instead hangs forever. Here is an MCVE:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(){
  std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Using g++ (GCC) 4.8.5, this never returns. I've also tried system_clock with the same results. Using strace to examine what's happening, the last thing I get is:

```
nanosleep({4294967295, 0},
```

so I guess it would return eventually, but I don't feel like waiting that long.

Is this a g++ bug? I can't imagine this behavior is intentional. I found the question [Is behaviour well-defined when `sleep_until()` specifies a time point in the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848236/is-behaviour-well-defined-when-sleep-until-specifies-a-time-point-in-the-pas) but it doesn't seem that any conclusion was actually reached on whether or not the standard actually specifies what should happen. I've since implemented another solution to my problem; I'm just curious as to whether or not what I'm seeing is UB or a bug.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  On 4.9 or newer it does not hang.

Comment: My answer was wrong, so I deleted it. The wording in the standard doesn't really specify, as far as I can parse it, what happens when the time_point passed is in the past. It still looks like a bug, though.

Comment: It does specify, however, that if the clock is adjusted to after said time_point, it should wake as soon as possible. This is what I (wrongly) quoted in my answer.

Comment: @CássioRenan:  I'm the one that upvoted your answer before you deleted it, and I'm also the one who led the standardization process on `<chrono>` and the `_until` functions.  If the spec doesn't say this is a bug, then there's also a bug in the spec.  If you have suggestions on how to improve the spec, [here is how to go about that](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue).

Comment: @CássioRenan: If you like, I can vote to undelete your answer (so you don't have to re-type it if you are so inclined).

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks for your comments! I'm not really sure where to start on suggesting improvements, since I'm not sure I got everything right. About the answer: I could undelete it, since I deleted it myself, but it's still wrong, because it doesn't answer the question. (The clock is never *adjusted during the timeout* in the question).

Comment: If I were writing the answer, I would do what you did, except emphasize "Given a clock time point argument Ct, the clock time point of the return from timeout should be Ct+Di+Dm when the clock is not adjusted during the timeout.".  Then note that this is true whether or not Ct is in the past or future, and the implementation _should_ strive to minimize Di and Dm (which are both non-negative).

Comment: @HowardHinnant I know Stackoverflow is not really the place for "Thanks" and all of that, but I must say our small exchange here inspired me to study more, and I finally can read this section of the standard and understand it well enough to say I know what I'm talking about, which I was not confortable with doing before. So, thanks a lot! (BTW, the bug is fixed on gcc: I've updated the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a bug:

> #### 30.2.4 Timing specifications [thread.req.timing]
>
> [4](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing#4)  
>   The functions whose names end in `_­until` take an argument that specifies a time point.
>   These functions produce absolute timeouts.
>   Implementations should use the clock specified in the time point to measure time for these functions.
>   **Given a clock time point argument C<sub>t</sub>, the clock time point of the return from timeout should be C<sub>t</sub>+D<sub>i</sub>+D<sub>m</sub> when the clock is not adjusted during the timeout.**
>   (...)

Where D<sub>i</sub> is defined as a "quality of implementation" delay, and D<sub>m</sub> is defined as a "quality of management" delay.

[As Howard Hinnant brilliantly emphasizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755266/sleep-until-a-timepoint-in-the-past/51755506#comment90471485_51755266), an implementation should strive to minimize D<sub>i</sub> and D<sub>m</sub>:

> #### 30.2.4 Timing specifications [thread.req.timing]
>
> [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.req.timing#2)  
>   Implementations necessarily have some delay in returning from a timeout.
>   Any overhead in interrupt response, function return, and scheduling induces a “quality of implementation” delay, expressed as duration D<sub>i</sub>.
>   **Ideally, this delay would be zero**.
>   Further, any contention for processor and memory resources induces a “quality of management” delay, expressed as duration D<sub>m</sub>.
>   **The delay durations may vary from timeout to timeout, but in all cases shorter is better.**

Note that this must be true no matter what the value of C<sub>t</sub> is, and that an **infinite** delay is definitely not minimal.

As a small update, [this is now fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6609fedbefc78776), as of version 4.9.3. [Here is the information on the bug tracker.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58038)